# how could find code of Matlab mex file?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

I want to convert Imrotate function of Matlab to c++.
Matlab used a mex file(Imrotatemex) in Imrotate.
how could find code of Matlab mex file?

Comment: As far as I know you can't. from 2006: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/138604 and the answer is more or less the same in 2009: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98627-how-do-i-access-the-source-code-for-built-in-functions-in-matlab so I doubt this have changed by now.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the function matlab uses by typing using

```
edit imrotate
```

Also, the documentation says:

```
%   Performance Note
%   ----------------
%   This function may take advantage of hardware optimization for datatypes
%   uint8, uint16, and single to run faster.
```

Matlab calls imrotatemex in this case, that is C code that has been compiled to be called from Matlab, and is generally faster.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`which`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) displays the full path for the specified item and supports matlab functions, java methods, workspace variables and any file in the current working folder or on the matlab path:

```
which('imrotate')
which imrotate
```

If you supply it with the parameter `'-all'`, it will list all found references:

```
which imrotate -all
```

Of course, if the code is obfuscated ([pcode](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html), [shared library](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-functions-in-shared-libraries.html) or others), there is not much to edit.

Answer (score 0):

After I reviewed the top two answers. The command

```
which imrotatemex -all
```

gives me the result:

/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/toolbox/images/images/private/imrotatemex.mexmaci64  % Private to images

As you can see, it is in a private file

refer to the method in this answer, we have two method to access it:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7583520?start=0&tstart=0

1.Use the 'Go' function in finder

use the path /Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/toolbox/images/images/private/

2.Use terminal and enter the command:

defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

After I searched for some results, mexmaci64 is a file compiled by a c file in matlab, therefore we can't edit it directly.(? leave this as a question)

From another aspect, OpenCV may have some implementation based on C.

Regards,
Lin